# How to Display multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
/************** Retrieving Data from database ****************/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '17' AND team != '0'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$i = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $bpkmn_id[$i] = $rows['pkmn_id'];   
    $battle_level[$i] = $rows['level']; 
    $battle_health[$i] = $rows['health'];
    $path = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$bpkmn_id[$i]."' ");
    $battle_poke[$i] = mysql_result($path,0,"path");
    $i++;
}

$i = 0; /******** Storing retrieved data in Multidimensional array ***********/
while($i <= 5)
{
$battlepokemons = array
(
    $pokemon[$i] = array('battle_poke' => $battle_poke[$i], 'battle_level' => $battle_level[$i], 'battle_health' => $battle_health[$i])
);
$i++;
}
```

I retrieved the data first then stored it in multidimensional array! 
Now I want to display it! I tried on my own... and also tried Stackoverflow with solutions,
But didn't found any that can solve my problem.

I just want to know how to display it, just need a perfect idea for my code!

Comment: If you cant ans.. dont answer..! Don't start giving negative rating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use foreach() two times

```
 <?php

      $battlepokemons = array
    (
        $pokemon[$i] = array('battle_poke' => $battle_poke[$i], 'battle_level' => $battle_level[$i], 'battle_health' => $battle_health[$i])
    );
        foreach($battlepokemons as $me)
        {
        $test= $me;
        foreach($test as $me1)
        {
        echo $me1;
        }
        }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Yaa The logic is correct! I will apply it.. and it will work :)!